# Does multi part file upload creates multiple requests

Tags: servlets, file-upload, httprequest, servlet-filters, multifile-uploader

I see lot of detailed answers on how file upload works. What I need to know is that does a multi part file upload create multiple requests.

What I am trying to do is to create a filter that filters out some contents from a file when it is uploaded. If the file upload creates multiple requests then the data I need to remove may be split in multiple requests and may pass through the filter.

Answer (score 2):

Multi part file upload will be a single http request. In the same http request there will be boundaries between each file.